# On $(k,\ell)$-sumfree sets

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, infinite-combinatorics

Call a set $\mathcal S \subset \mathbb N$ to be $(k,\ell)$-sumfree if there are no non-trivial solutions to the equation
$$x_1+\dots +x_k = y_1+\dots +y_\ell$$
in the set (for distinct $x_i$'s and $y_j$'s).

For example, a (close kin of) $(2,1)$-sumfree set is what is known just as a sumfree set in literature, and (close kin of) an $(h,h)$-sumfree set is what is usually called a $\mathbf B_h$ set (the $h=2$ case being called a *Sidon set*). The *close kin* part is because these things do not demand distinctness.

I am interested in infinite sets that are $(k,\ell)$-sumfree **for all** natural numbers $k$ and $\ell$ with $k\ell>1$. An example of such a set is the set of powers of $2$.

Does this kind of set have any name? Has anyone studied them so far? If yes, then what are the known results? What questions have been asked or answered? In particular, I am looking for density results and structures (if possible).

---

It has been pointed out that such sets are known as dissociated sets in literature. However, the only work that is available deals with dissociated sets in finite abelian groups. I am interested in studying infinite dissociated sets in natural numbers, and I have not been able to find any literature regarding this topic. I will be grateful if anybody can point me to any work that has been done regarding this.

Comment: Google for something like Erdos Straus Deshouillers Freiman admissible set.

Comment: @Seva Thanks for the reference!

Comment: @Seva Please note that admissible sets are defined as a set $A$ such that whenever an integer can be written as a sum of $s$ distinct elements from $A$, then $s$ is well defined. This does not include the property of having a unique representation, and hence such sets are a bit different than the ones I am concerned with. In fact, one of the first theorems in the paper says that such sets will have arithmetic progressions (which is not true in my case).

Comment: These are often called dissociated sets (although that term can mean different things in some contexts).

Comment: @ThomasBloom Thank you for your comment, sir. A quick google search with the term _dissociated sets_ only yielded [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.1074.pdf) by Prof. Shkredov which is discussing dissociated subsets of $\mathbf F_2^n$. Do you know of any references which tries to find infinite dissociated subsets of $\mathbb N$?

Comment: What kind of thing do you want to know exactly? The existence of infinite dissociated sets is trivial, as you say.

Comment: @ThomasBloom mainly, I'm concerned about size (and any structures, if possible). The powers of 2 has size $\log n$ and I believe that a $(k,\ell)-$sumfree set can't perform any better than at most a power of $\log n$... Is that true?

Comment: To be clear the property you're interested in is that the map from the set of finite subsets of $S$ to $\mathbb N$ which takes a subset to its sum is injective? Certainly if such a set has $m$ elements $\leq n$ then $2^m \leq m n+1 $ which gives $m \leq \log_2(n) + o( \log_2(n))$.

Comment: @WillSawin That was a very elegant argument, sir! Do you know of any structures such sets have to contain?